# Added numpy array into the TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a beginner in TensorFlow and I need an advice. I have a lot of images (I have their filenames) and I want to pass `[image, preprocess_array1, preprocess_array2]` to TensorFlow graph. (preprocess_array1 and preprocess_array2 are some arrays with data based on images information: for example depth of each pixel, so some data - it doesn't matter.) I have the working pipeline but only for images (using QueueRunner in `tf.train.string_input_producer`) So, what is the easiest way to add my arrays into graph with images? Is it possible to add in a queue?

P.S. All my preprocessing code for image used Numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you should look into are so called [placeholders](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder). They allow you to define a Tensorflow graph with unknown input, which is later at runtime fed into the graph by using feed dictionaries. You only need to specify the shape of the placeholders. Every axis except for one must be known in advance. The unspecified axis is reserved for batches and can be defined by giving `None` as axis length.

I'll give an example of how to feed a batch of simple numpy arrays (images) into a Tensorflow graph and calculate the mean image (just for demonstration):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# define the placeholder for the arrays (images)
A = tf.placeholder(tf.int16, shape=(None, 1024, 1024))
# calculate the mean image for this batch
mean = tf.reduce_mean(A, axis=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create 42 random black & white images in numpy
    batch = np.round(np.random.uniform(size=(42, 1024, 1024))*255)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        mean_image = sess.run(mean, feed_dict={A: batch})
        print(mean_image)
```